# Apply texture to grid

Tags: grid, processing

I would like to apply a texture to a grid in 3d space using Processing, I've tried declaring a PImage and setting the .jpg file with loadimage with no results..

```
    PImage tex;

    void setup()  {    
size(800, 600, P3D);   
 tex=loadImage("ground104"); 
noCursor(); 
}  
void draw() 
  {    
directionalLight(255, 255, 255, 0, 0, -1); 
   background(180); 
   drawPlane();  
}    
void drawPlane()
  {  //lights(); 
   int s = 10000;  
        int ss = 500;
         fill(0, 200, 20);   stroke(200);    for(int i = 0; i < s; i += ss)    {
        stroke(0,100,0);
        strokeWeight(3);
        beginShape(QUAD_STRIP);
        for(int j = 0; j <= s; j += ss)
        {
          texture(tex);
          vertex(j, i, 0);
          vertex(j, i + ss, 0);
        }
        endShape();    }    noStroke();  }
```

Do you have any advice?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need a file extension like .jpg. You can troubleshoot by running the code from the reference page:

http://www.processing.org/reference/texture_

```
size(100, 100, P3D);
noStroke();
PImage img = loadImage("laDefense.jpg");
beginShape();
texture(img);
vertex(10, 20, 0, 0);
vertex(80, 5, 100, 0);
vertex(95, 90, 100, 100);
vertex(40, 95, 0, 100);
endShape();
```

and replace laDefense.jpg with your image name. Also, it needs to be placed in the data directory in the sketch directory. If it works, then your problem is elsewhere. I am not sure what your plan is in the sketch, but you might find peasycam useful for troubleshooting in 3d.

http://mrfeinberg.com/peasycam/

another technique is to increment a float by 0.01 per frame and call a RotateX(), Y or Z or all of the above at the beginning of your draw() method / loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply!
I've changed my code to this and now you can run it and see what I get (first download the grass.jpg from https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsda0tih67q8tll/grass.jpg?m). I'm close but I wonder why the grid is green when it was supposed to be a grass land...

```
PImage tex;

void setup()  
{    
size(800, 600, P3D);   
tex=loadImage("grass.jpg"); 
noCursor(); 
}  

void draw() 
{ 
  translate(width/2 , height/2 , 0);  // center of screen
    rotateX(QUARTER_PI * 1.0);            // move camera up
    rotateZ(QUARTER_PI * 1.8);
    //rotateZ(camZ.val + offset);           // rotate around turret

    rotateZ(map(mouseX, mouseY, width, 2.5, -2.5));

    translate(-1000, 0, -1000);
  directionalLight(255, 255, 255, 0, 0, -1); 
  background(180); 
  drawPlane();  
}    
void drawPlane()
  {  //lights(); 
   int s = 10000;  
        int ss = 500;
         fill(0, 200, 20);   stroke(200);    for(int i = 0; i < s; i += ss)    {
        stroke(0,100,0);
        strokeWeight(3);
        beginShape(QUAD_STRIP);
        for(int j = 0; j <= s; j += ss)
        {
          texture(tex);
          vertex(j, i, 0);
          vertex(j, i + ss, 0);
        }
        endShape();
    }    
noStroke();
  }
```

Comment: either `fill(0, 200, 20);` or `stroke(0,100,0);` If I were to guess, most likely the stroke. I would suggest removing all of the fill, stroke and strokeWeight calls if you are applying a texture.